# Weird List/Collection behaviour - Adding an object vs property of an object

Tags: apex, list

Can someone explain this weird behaviour of List? I am trying to call a Webservice which returns me an object `SyncClientLicenseInfoWS.LicenseInfoWrapper`, which is an inner class.

When i add this returned object from the webservice call to a List, I see that the List has only the lastly added record repeated 2 times.

When I try to retrieve a property of the object from the returned object and add it to a List, it is behaving as expected, i wasted the whole day figuring this out and have no clue !

**//webservice class**

```
SyncClientLicenseInfoWS syncClientWS = new SyncClientLicenseInfoWS();
List<Access_Control__C> aclList = [select User_Name__c, User_Name_Email__c, Password__c 
                                    from Access_Control__c where Active__c= true];
//Creating Object List
List<SyncClientLicenseInfoWS.LicenseInfoWrapper> licList = 
            new List<SyncClientLicenseInfoWS.LicenseInfoWrapper>();
//Creating String List to hold the property of the object
List<String> licStrList = new List<String>();

SyncClientLicenseInfoWS.LicenseInfoWrapper wrapper1 = syncClientWS.queryClient(aclList[0]);
licStrList.add(wrapper1.jobScienceVersion);//Adding 1st object property to List
licList.add(wrapper1);//Adding 1st object to List
System.debug('wrapper1=='+wrapper1);
```

**My debug output**

```
//|DEBUG|wrapper1==LicenseInfoWrapper:[accId=001O000000l2Lw0IAE,     //jobScienceVersion=4.500.5]

SyncClientLicenseInfoWS.LicenseInfoWrapper wrapper2 = syncClientWS.queryClient(aclList[1]);
licStrList.add(wrapper2.jobScienceVersion);//Adding 2nd object property to List
licList.add(wrapper2)//Adding 2nd object to List<br/>
System.debug('wrapper2=='+wrapper2);<br/>
```

**My debug output (cont'd)**

```
DEBUG|wrapper2==LicenseInfoWrapper:[accId=001O000000l2Lw5IAE,jobScienceVersion=4.350.62]<br/>
System.debug('licList=='+licList);
```

**My debug output (cont'd)**

```
DEBUG|licList==(LicenseInfoWrapper:[accId=001O000000l2Lw5IAE,jobScienceVersion=4.350.62], (already output))
for(SyncClientLicenseInfoWS.LicenseInfoWrapper objWrapper:licList)
{
   System.debug('List of Wrapper'+objWrapper);
//Displays 2 instances of the last object      
}
```

**My debug output (cont'd)**

```
DEBUG|List of WrapperLicenseInfoWrapper:[accId=001O000000l2Lw5IAE, ,jobScienceVersion=4.350.62]

DEBUG|List of WrapperLicenseInfoWrapper:[accId=001O000000l2Lw5IAE, ,jobScienceVersion=4.350.62]


for(String strWrapper:licStrList)
{
    System.debug('List of Wrapper Str'+strWrapper);//displays 2 property values of 2 objects
}
```

**My debug output (cont'd)**

```
DEBUG|List of Wrapper Str4.500.5<br/>
DEBUG|List of Wrapper Str4.350.62
```

Please note that when i tried to manually create the objects of the inner class SyncClientLicenseInfoWS.LicenseInfoWrapper & add, it behaves as expected, it acts weird only when it is returned from the webservice call. I also made sure it is returning 2 different objects by printing them.
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: can u add debug statements for aclList, wrapper1 and wrapper2 and update your question with the debug output for all the variables

Comment: what's in the debug output for licList ? can you print it before you loop thru it ?

Comment: `queryClient` doesn't empty `licList` before each call? (although it's not clear how it would have addressability..hmm)

Comment: queryClient just returns an object instance of the class SyncClientLicenseInfoWS.LicenseInfoWrapper, which seems to be returning a different object as expected. Its just the List licList  behaving very unexpected.